# Creating a Class & Object

Tags: php

I'm somewhat new to php, I have really good knowledge of Java & C#. Usually in C# & Java to create a class I would normally do

```
public class Student { 

public String name;
public int age;

public Student(name, age){
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}


}
```

How would I do this in php?

Thanks

Comment: How? By start learning PHP OOP here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

Answer (score 2):

The differences you will encounter revolve around variable types (PHP has magical variables that take any types.)  Secondly, the constructor doesn't require a type:

```
class Student {
    public $name;
    public $age;

    function __construct($name, $age) {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->age = $age;
    }
}

$pp = new Student("pp19dd", 123456);
```

Comment: You will note that PHP is not typed as C# and Java are so its worth mentioning if you want to enforce those types you need to do so in your constructor or setters. PHP does have [type hinting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php) for classes and arrays though.

Comment: Those properties will work as `public`, but they would be better as `protected`, for encapsulation.